# getCurrentPosition on chrome breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page where I am loading google maps. I use getCurrentPosition over http and even I receive a warning from google api. The problem is that it breaks also the javascript and that ruins everything. The code was working for quite some time but the last week things broke.

Below is the html and script. You can add it in html and run it and see (tried with stackoverflow but had some issues with the script)

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

</head>
<body>
    <header class="desktop">

    </header>
    <div id="st-container" class="st-container">
        <div class="st-pusher">

            <div class="st-content">
                <div class="st-content-inner">
                    <div class="logo-mobile">
                    </div>
                    <section class="map-sections">
                        <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; width: 100%; margin-top: 30px;">
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="large-12 columns">
                                <div class="filter clearfix">
                                   <input type="text" id="search-field" placeholder="Search place">
                                   <span>eller...</span>
                                   <a href="#" id="search-button" class="btn pink geolocate" onclick="showMap('true');">Search near you</a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="google_canvas"></div>
                           <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
                           <script type="text/javascript">
                              function showMap(userPos) {

                                 if (!!navigator.geolocation) {

                                    var map;

                                    if (userPos == 'true') {
                                       var mapOptions = {
                                          zoom: 12,
                                          enableHighAccuracy: true,
                                          mapTypeControl: false,
                                          streetViewControl: false,
                                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                       };
                                    }
                                    else {
                                       var mapOptions = {
                                          zoom: 5,
                                          enableHighAccuracy: false,
                                          mapTypeControl: false,
                                          streetViewControl: false,
                                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                       };
                                    }

                                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_canvas'), mapOptions);

                                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                                       var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                                       var sectionList = [
                                           ['Stockholm', 59.327, 18.067],
                                           ['Göteborg', 57.70889, 11.97348]
                                       ];

                                       var mapPinUser = '/dist/img/map-pin-user.png';
                                       var mapPinSection = '/dist/img/map-pin-section.png';

                                       // User's position
                                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                          position: geolocate,
                                          map: map,
                                          icon: mapPinUser,
                                          title: "ok"
                                       });

                                       for (var i = 0; i < sectionList.length; i++) {
                                          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                             position: new google.maps.LatLng(sectionList[i][1], sectionList[i][2]),
                                             map: map,
                                             icon: mapPinSection,
                                             id: i,
                                             animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                             title: sectionList[i][0]
                                          });
                                       }

                                       if (userPos == 'true') {
                                          map.panTo(geolocate);
                                       }
                                       else {
                                          map.setCenter({ lat: 61.58549, lng: 15.02930 });
                                       }

                                    });

                                 } else {
                                    document.getElementById('google_canvas').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
                                 }

                              }

                              showMap('false');
                           </script>
                        <style>
                            #google_canvas {
                                height: 65vh;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the warning in the javascript console, getCurrentLocation is only supported over HTTPS.

Comment: Fair enough but the code was working like last week without https. Was that a last minute change?

Comment: There has been a warning in place in the javascript console in Chrome for quite a while, and it was announced a while ago.

Comment: Updated Comment: 
I have found the issue here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Firefox works. It is not that good that I have to change everything on https now but from the other hand of course it is good to use that over http.

Comment: @geocodezip Anyhow your answer is correct. I should go with https if I need to solve this. Instead I removed the code related to users location. I am not sure also why I cant mark your comment as the correct answer.

Comment: You can't mark comments as accepted answers. I have taken the information from the comments and added that as an answer if you want to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCurrentLocation is only supported over `https://` now on Chrome.

There has been a warning in place in the javascript console in Chrome for quite a while, and it was announced a while ago.

[reference from your comment](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

> Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the user’s location using the HTML5 Geolocation API from pages delivered by non-secure connections. This means that the page that’s making the Geolocation API call must be served from a secure context such as HTTPS.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!