# chrome browser doesnt show marker - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

In firefox, my marker shows fine but in chrome, it doesn't show anything.
I think chrome doesn't allow me to access to the current user location.
because marker shows the current location of the user.

my codes:

```
 initialize();
            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
                    center: {lat: 35.6961111, lng: 51.4230556},
                    zoom: 13
                });
            }

 getLocation();
            function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else {
                    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
            }
            function showPosition(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                getAddress(lat,lng);
                initialize(lat,lng);
            }




            //START FIND LOCATION

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var marker = null;
            var map = null;
            function initialize(lat,lng) {
                //var $latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
               // var $longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
                var latitude = lat;
                var longitude = lng;
                var zoom = 16;

                var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: zoom,
                    center: LatLng,
                    panControl: false,
                    zoomControl: false,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
                if (marker && marker.getMap) marker.setMap(map);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Drag Me!',
                    draggable: true
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker) {
                    var latLng = marker.latLng;
                    getAddress(latLng.lat(),latLng.lng());
                });


            }
```

my url:

http://www.khadamatchi.com/frontend/Index/addAddressByUser

Comment: there are some google code examples of how to handle geolocation on https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/ (which is not the link in the below answer)  ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [getCurrentPosition on chrome breaks javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125514/getcurrentposition-on-chrome-breaks-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [navigator.geolocation not working in google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415413/navigator-geolocation-not-working-in-google-chrome)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetcurrentPosition doesn't work once deployed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192827/getcurrentposition-doesnt-work-once-deployed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome only allows accessing a user's location when the webpage is served over `https`. 
[See this Google Developers Blog post for more information](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)